# M2.2 Integrations issue with extensions

Tags: magento2, integration, magento-social

Every time I install an extension I receive the error displayed in the screenshot. If I click on the **"integrations"** link it takes me to `System/Integrations`.

I then activate Magento Social and the message disappears. However, a few days later the same message appears again. Why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** Magento 2 install extension using COMMAND LINE (Recommended)

Your Magento 2 extensions can be installed in a few minutes by going through these following steps

Step 1: Download/purchase the extension

Step 2: Unzip the file into a temporary directory

Step 3: Upload it to your Magento installation root directory

Step 4: Disable the cache under `System­ >> Cache Management`

Step 5: Enter the following at the command line:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**Option 2 :** add an extension's package to the root composer.json

then run `composer update`

then run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

**Option 3 :** You can also install extension from admin panel component manager as well , for more details please refer this link - https://magefan.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-2-extension-2/

Comment: I use option 1. The installations themselves are fine. Only the error message shows.